# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy' from user input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've this dataframe:

```
dtf = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['Buenos Dias'],
         'col2' : ["Hello"],
         'col3' : ["Bonjour"]})
```

I need to accept user input  dataframe name using this fonction and make a copy.
I get an error message "'str' object has no attribute 'copy' "
So, how translate this "str" into pandas ?

```
def copydf():
    global dfNewName
    dfname = input(" Enter dataframe Name :")
    print (dfname)
    dfNewName = dfname.copy()
```

Thank you if you can help.

Comment: why do you need a "copy" why not just use the string you got from the input?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Where should the user input go? You're receiving an error because you are trying to use the copy method on a string (user input is always a string like "hello world").

Maybe you are expecting `dfname` to be a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Yes the Idea is to create a copy "dfNewName" from the dataframe "dtf"

Comment: @JacobIRR - That's the issue, what returns from the input it's just a string, is not recognized  by pandas.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the user input with [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function.

```
import pandas as pd

dtf = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['Buenos Dias'],
     'col2' : ["Hello"],
     'col3' : ["Bonjour"]})

def copydf():
    dfname = input(" Enter dataframe Name :")
    try:
        newdf = eval(dfname).copy()
        return newdf
    except NameError:
        print("Dataframe not found")


new_df= copydf() #this is your copied dataframe
```

Comment: It looked good but I get another error message : ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: That's simply perfect. You're great.Thank you

Comment: Please, mark it as the right answer i will really appreciate it if you do it

Comment: I must insist, please mark the answer as the solution, i will really appreciate it if you do it